# Different class (textcolor) in javascript form

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, colors

I have the problem that I can't set two different text colors (via css classes) in the following javascript form. The standard class is grey (grey text color), but once someone clicks on "Type your mail here" the email color text to type in, should be black. (class black). Someone can help me?

```
<form name="mainform" method="post">
     Your email: <input type="text" size="40" class="grey" name="email" value="{{ fields.email.input }}" onclick="ClearIfAppropriate();">{{ fields.email.error }} &nbsp; <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
    var LabelText = "Type your email here";
    if(document.mainform.email.value.length == 0) {
        document.mainform.email.value = LabelText;
    }
    function ClearIfAppropriate() {
        if(document.mainform.email.value == LabelText) {
            document.mainform.email.value = "";
            document.mainform.email.class = "black";
        }
    }
//--></script>
```

CSS Classes

```
.grey {
    color: grey;
}

.black {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you want to change is

```
className
```

See here http://www.jsfiddle.net/dduncan/hdtvr/

Comment: And the reason being that `class` is a reserved future keyword.

Answer (score 3):

This is easily doable in pure CSS No javascript is necessary:

```
input.grey:focus
{
   color: #000;
}
```

Although I think ie<8 doesn't support the pseudo-class `:focus`.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your input (id="idElement") and

instead of: document.mainform.email.class = "black";

try:

document.getElementById("idElement").setAttribute("class", "className");

Should do it.